# Linux wget, how to display progress percentage after session has reload?

Tags: linux, wget, progress

I am running debian Squeeze in console mode on a plug computer. I control it opening an SSH session from a Windows machine, on the same local network.

I started downloading a large file using wget.

What I get is a console progress bar showing the percentage of data downloaded, file size, and download rate.

When I close the session, debian is still running and downloading. Fine.

But When I close and reopen a session, how can see which amount of data was downloaded, using a linux command ?

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use a program like `screen` or `tmux` to preserve your remote terminal sessions while you're not connected.

Comment: There is another solution. Install a vnc server, and access it from another machine, opening a vnc session. I just get the debian session in the state before leaving.

Answer (score 2):

To answer *"how can see which amount of data was downloaded, using a linux command?"* only, in the download directory use any of the follow

```
ls -l
ls -s
ls -sh <download filename>
```

That will show you the file size already download/written to your disk.

Comment: ok. Thank you both for you help.
I finally found an easy solution: just look at the last line in wget-log which is written and updated by the task wget, while processing.
wget write a line in the file and display it on screen. The problem is, I cannot see the display anymore, after I close session.
I'll have a try to the screen command to see if it give me back the current display when i open a new ssh session, while wget-log is still growing.

Answer (score 2):

wget normally logs its output to the `wget-log` file in the download directory. To display this file and its changes, execute the following command in the download directory:

```
$ tail -f wget-log
```